# Remove hyphen and space using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have following dataset and wants remove hyphen and whitespaces.

For example:

Original Dataset:

[image]

Expected Results:

[image]

Actual Results which I got like below

[image]

Code Snippet which I followed,

dataframe.withColumn("colNew", regexp_replace('colNew'), '-', '')

Answer (score 0):

`regexp_replace(col("input"),"[\\s-]","")` .This will replace all whitespaces and hyphen